# C++ Access member of struct/class using map

Tags: c++, list, search, mapping, member

I need to search a database made up of a linked list of pointers to a struct called Person. Inside Person there is a bunch of data - first name, last name, social security, etc.  It's all fictional and inconsequential.  My problem is that I need to do a search based on user input, which determines what part of the struct is being compared for the search.  Since all of the data is stored as members of the struct Person, I think the best way to do this (as in not writing 8 search functions) is by mapping, but my grasp of mapping is so poor as to be nearly non-existent.  Here is the relevant code:

```
List * find(List * database, //mapping stuff, string name)
{
     //run search
     return database;
}

void search(List * database)
{
    string field, searchtype, userinput;
    cout << "To search for a person, enter information in this format: 'field equal
    value' or 'field begins value'. Type 'clear' to 
    return to original database. Type 'exit' to leave the program\n";

while(field != "exit")
{
    cin >> field >> searchtype >> userinput;
    if(userinput == "firstname")  //this is just for example, I would have to write one of these out for each parameter.
    {
        List * smallerdb = find(database, map(//mapping stuff?), string userinput);
    }
}
}
```

This is for school, so please don't suggest I just use another library, as I can't.  Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to map. You need a parameterized *comparator* that is initialized to a "state" of which fields to compare. Then use that comparator (likely a functor) when comparing your items.

Comment: Maybe you want to pass a pointer-to-member into your search function, and use that to get the data to search from each item in the list.

Comment: I think I was mistaking the functor for mapping, but I'm still very vague on functors.  Do you think you could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Each data-type will have to be compared differently, so without explicitly knowing the data-types you are out of luck. Strings are compared alphabetically, numbers are compared by value, and i'm not sure if you have any other custom data-types.

So you don't really have much of an option here besides going through each of the case-by-case scenarios. E.g.

```
    if type == 'name'                // compare each Person.name as string
    else if type == 'socialSecurity' // compare Person.socialSecurity as int
    else if ...
```

Here is a suggestion for making this code a bit more robust.

Instead of handling the search logic in each of the cases, you can simply return a function pointer than tells you how to compare two `Persons`. The *actual* function may be comparing by name, age, social security, or whatever, but your search function won't have to care about that once it has the function pointer that tells it how to compare two `Person` objects.